# SqlDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable) Returns No Rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I am trying to use a `SqlDataAdapter` to fill a `DataTable`, which I use as a data source to a `DataGrid`. The query is fine, at least when I run it manually in SSMSE. When I do the fill operation, the table gets the right columns, but no rows. The most frustrating part of this is that the code is identical (with a different query) on a different page. I cannot post the query, but my initialization code looks like this:

```
SqlCommand areaDAC = new SqlCommand (areaQuery, connection);
areaDAC.Parameters.Add (new SqlParameter ("@param",
    System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50));
m_areaDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter (areaDAC);
```

Then to use it:

```
m_areaDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters["@param"].Value = "Filter Val";
DataTable table = new DataTable ();
m_areaDataAdapter.Fill (table);
```

At this point, table has the right number of columns and no rows. I know the parameters are being added correctly, I know that data exists for the given query.

**Update** (as provided by Nik in a comment):

```
SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DateAndTime DESC) AS rowNum, 
       areaName, stationName, lineName, DateAndTime, 
       Element, Description 
    FROM 
       sdrReportArea, sdrReportStation, sdrReportTLine, 
       SDRSequenceEvents, SDRSequenceStates 
    WHERE 
       sdrReportArea.areaID = sdrReportStation.stationID 
       AND sdrReportStation.stationID = sdrReportTLine.stationID 
       AND sdrReportTLine.lineID = SDRSequenceEvents.LineID 
       AND SDRSequenceEvents.StateID = SDRSequenceStates.StateID 
       AND DateAndTime >= @startDate AND DateAndTime <= @endDate 
       AND areaName = @area) AS TempTbl 
WHERE 
    rowNum BETWEEN @startRow AND @endRow;
```

Comment: Have you tested the SQL query directly in SQL Manager? Are you catching exceptions and examining them for clues?

Comment: I would recommend you check our connection string as well. Is it possible that the query that works is going to a different version of the database that doesn't have the data you're looking for?

Comment: The query works fine manually. The connection string is OK and matches the server I tested manually against. There are no exceptions when I run the C# code. The purpose of the rowNum column is to window the data, only 50 rows at a time, which again, works fine manually.

Comment: All of the parameters are populated correctly beforehand as well.

Comment: @Nik: Please update your question with the information you posted in the comment. This has nothing to do with ASP.NET or C#, so why put them in the title?

Comment: One recommendation: **use standard ANSI JOIN's** (`INNER JOIN, LEFT OUTER JOIN` etc.) and **don't use those old-style "table1, table2, table3......" joins** anymore. Those are hard to read and understand and susceptible to unwantingly introducign a Cartesian product!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Try removing the date type parameter in where clause and test again.
2. And I faced such problem With typed dataset where "Over" not work(IMO), so I guess it will not work here too. Use SPs instead if possible.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. I know about the differences between queries and SPs, but how would an SP help me here. My table ends up with the right columns, just no data.

Comment: I guess the actual problem lies with plain sql query which uses Row_Number And Over. And I faced such issues with typeddatasets while doing custom pagination. So later on I moved that queries too Stored Procedure and that worked. So as I said if possible try placing it into SP.

Comment: Ended up creating a stored procedure, though with that I also had to pass my date and time parameters as strings and convert them inside of the SP.

Comment: "I also had to pass my date and time parameters as strings" - I suspect passing them as strings was your problem.  You should have passed them as SqlDateTime.  Probably the date format of your string did not match that used by the connection.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could try might be to run ExecuteReader and iterate through the results.

```
IDataReader reader = m_areaDataAdapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
while(reader.Read())
{
    ...
}
```

This might help you to see if the problem is with your command, or with your DataTable.

> I know the parameters are being added correctly, I know that data exists for the given query

When you're debugging, you should question all your assumptions, including this one.  Note also that when executing queries manually using SSMSE, your connection may be configured differently (e.g. ANSI NULLS, ANSI PADDING) and therefore give different results.

**EDIT**

In response to Nik's comment, here are some suggestions for debugging this.

1. Run similar code, but modifying the query so that it does not have any parameters (i.e. hardwired values for start/end date, area, start/end row).  If this doesn't work, then it seems likely that your connection may be configured differently from SSMSE.  If it does work, then ...
2. Add parameters to your query one by one until it fails.  You will then be able to identify which parameter caused it to fail.  Likely the penny will drop and you'll see why (e.g. parameter name misspelt?), if not, post the code here.

Comment: How would I check things like ANSI NULLS? The data reader isn't returning any data either. I say the parameters are being added correctly because before stuff executes, I check the parameters and their values in memory, and they are set right. Is there something that I have to explicitly say to use parameters?

Answer (score 1):

I was just having a similar problem with `OracleDataAdapter`. I was trying to even do a simple

`select * from table`

and it wasn't working. I ended up setting the

`DbCommand.CommandTimeout`

property and it began to work. I'm still confused, though, because I have previously never had to set these properties.

Comment: In your case, your network connection was timing out too quickly, either because of poor bandwidth/throughput, or your DB server was too busy to get to, and/or process, the command.  You did the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you accessing the query through a webservice that executes the ADO.NET call? If the server's timezone is different, the values for @StartDate and @EndDate may not be what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

There may be problem between your join by Multiple WHERE Clause. You have to find out that whatever table are join on specific ID is correct or not as per your database table and data.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, though I don't know if it addresses the OP's question, but may help someone:

I had an issue where I was getting no rows returned and an exception `Cannot find table 0`, using similar code to use the adapter to fill a dataset (which automatically creates a table in the dataset).

Relevant snippet of code (doesn't show OracleCommand, connection opening, for simplicity):

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
OracleDataAdapter oraAdp = new OracleDataAdapter();

oraAdp.Fill(ds);
return ds.Tables[0];
```

I knew the query I was sending via an OracleCommand should have done the fill and gotten results - or so I thought.  When I ran the query in Oracle SQL Developer, I got the real exception, which was that I had the wrong field name in my query for one of the fields.  When I corrected my query, all came through fine.

Answer (score 0):

12 years later but I hit the problem when the sql does several steps and does a select at the end.

If you do `da.Fill(dataset)` it works, whereas `da.Fill(datatable)` did not work.

In my case the sql created a temp table via select..into, then it does a few updates, then it finally does a select statement to return the data at the end. This did not work directly into a datatable, but it works fine into a dataset.

Hope that helps someone :)